# Bootstrap carousel with Thumbnail more than 9 items

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use this script to slider:
http://www.bootply.com/79859
problem appear when the number of images exceeds 9.

Thumbnail number 10 redirect to slide 0

number 11 to slide 1

number 12 to slide 2
...

What is wrong with this code?

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
});

// handles the carousel thumbnails
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
  var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
  var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
  id = parseInt(id);
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
  $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});

// when the carousel slides, auto update
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
  var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
  id = parseInt(id);
  $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
  $('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Its' probably not this code that's wrong. How about showing us your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
```

It is assuming that the length of the number is 1 character long. Change it to this instead. This version starts just after the position of the last `-`:

```
var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.lastIndexOf("-")+1);
```